# extract valid and unique ip address from a file

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, ipython

I need to parse valid and unique ip address from a text file.

sample file to be parsed:

```
ping working 3.3.3.3
ping not working 8.8.8.888
ping working 5.5.55.6 ip address
I am repeat 3.3.3.3
invalid 0.0.0.266
I am not repeat 8.88.8.255
I am 255.255.255.0
I am 111.111.111.111
I am not valid 355.355.355.355
I am valid 192.168.99.1
```

Code:

```
import re
pattern = r"((([01]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])[ (\[]?(\.|dot)[ )\]]?){3}([01]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]))"

f = open("parse-me.txt","r")
text = f.read()

ips = [match[0] for match in re.findall(pattern, text)]
print list(set(ips))
```

When I run it, it gives following output:

```
python parse_ip.py
['111.111.111.111', '255.255.255.0', '192.168.99.1', '3.3.3.3', '0.0.0.26', '8.88.8.25', '5.5.55.6', '8.8.8.88']
```

Somehow last digit from 255 get missed in the output. Can someone help me in resolving this issue?

Comment: Could you try to use the following regex: `(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)` because i think the error is `25[0-5]` this one

Comment: My text doesn't start and end with ip address so cant use this regex with ^ and $, it gives [] as output.

Comment: @hek2mgl, dint get any perfect working solution, it will be great if you can point me one.

Comment: check this https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/regular-expressions-cookbook/9780596802837/ch07s16.html to write the correct Regular expression. after you get valid ips, use `set` to unique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might make more sense to rely on Python's own IP address validation as follows:

```
import socket
import re

valid = set()

with open('input.txt') as f_input:
    for ip in re.findall(r'(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})', f_input.read()):
        try:
            socket.inet_aton(ip)
            valid.add(ip)
        except socket.error:
            pass

print list(valid)
```

This would display

```
['111.111.111.111', '255.255.255.0', '8.88.8.255', '192.168.99.1', '3.3.3.3', '5.5.55.6']
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Problem will be solved if you use below regex:

```
    pattern = r"(((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9]?[0-9])[ (\[]?(\.|dot)[ )\]]?){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9]?[0-9]))"
```

as you can see i just rearranged your regex. Actually in "|" condition it won't go for second condition match if first condition comes true.

But careful this regex is still giving wrong result as it parsing 8.8.88.888 to 8.8.88.88

That is i guess answer your doubt but you need new regex

Answer (score -1):

Hope this will help

```
In[61]:
f = open("parse-me.txt","r")
text = f.read()
re.findall( r'[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}', text)

Out[62]:
['3.3.3.3',
 '8.8.8.888',
 '5.5.55.6',
 '3.3.3.3',
 '0.0.0.266',
 '8.88.8.255',
 '255.255.255.0',
 '111.111.111.111',
 '355.355.355.355',
 '192.168.99.1']
```